# How Can I separate characters and number from a word using SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How Can I separate characters and number from a word using SQL Server query?

Example word: `AB12C34DE`

The Output is like:

```
col1
-----    
ABCDE

col2
-----
1234
```

Comment: That doesn't look easy, does the column values share a common pattern or is the mix of letters and numbers random?

Comment: Which version of sql server?

Comment: I am using 2012 SQL Server version psk

Answer (score 9):

Please try this.

```
DECLARE @Numstring varchar(100)
SET @Numstring = 'AB12C34DE'
WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Numstring) <> 0.
SET @Numstring = STUFF(@Numstring,PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Numstring),1,'')
SELECT @Numstring As Number

DECLARE @Charstring varchar(100)
SET @Charstring = 'AB12C34DE'
WHILE PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]%',@Charstring) <> 0.
SET @Charstring = STUFF(@Charstring,PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]%',@Charstring),1,'')
SELECT @Charstring As Character
```

Comment: This might work, but is *procedural thinking*... SQL-Server demands for *set based* approaches... `WHILE` loops should be avoided if ever possible (as well as `CURSOR`)...

Comment: The problem with a `while` loop is that it works for a single string.  However, you cannot incorporate the logic into a query.

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @word VARCHAR(100)='AB12C34DE';

WITH Tally(Nmbr) AS
(
    SELECT TOP(LEN(@word)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM master..spt_values
)
,Separated AS
(
    SELECT CASE WHEN OneChar LIKE '[0-9]' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsDigit
          ,OneChar
          ,Nmbr
    FROM Tally
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(@word,Nmbr,1)) A(OneChar)
)
SELECT (SELECT OneChar AS [*] FROM Separated WHERE IsDigit=1 ORDER BY Nmbr FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS AllNumbers
      ,(SELECT OneChar AS [*] FROM Separated WHERE IsDigit=0 ORDER BY Nmbr FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS AllCharacters;
```

### Some explanation

The idea uses a tally table (a list of numbers). You might use an existing physical numbers table...

- The first CTE "Tally" will create a derived list of numbers (1,2,3, ...), one for each character.
- The second CTE will read each character *one-by-one* and mark it as digit or not.
- The final query will re-concatenate the list of characters

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `SQL Server 2012` so you can't use `TRANSLATE` which can simplify this.

One ways is to use `REPLACE` like following. If you want you can convert it to a user defined `function` so that you don't have to write same thing again and again.

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(VAL VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE SELECT 'AB12C34DE'

SELECT REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE (VAL, '0', ''),
'1', ''),
'2', ''),
'3', ''),
'4', ''),
'5', ''),
'6', ''),
'7', ''),
'8', ''),
'9', '') COL1,
REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE (VAL, 'A', ''),
'B', ''),
'C', ''),
'D', ''),
'E', ''),
'F', ''),
'6', ''),
'G', ''),
'H', ''),
'I', '') COL2
--ADD OTHER CHARACTERS

FROM @TABLE
```

Comment: I think this is a rather expensive approach... Each `REPLACE` will have to run through the whole string over and over... At the moment I have not the time to test the performance, but I'll set this on my list...

Comment: I am not sure @Shnugo , I will try to run this on some sample data.

Comment: @PSK . . . If  you showed the code with `TRANSLATE()` I would upvote.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I tried, butTRANSLATE also require one final REPLACE call as TRANSLATE is char <-> char translation. REPLACE(TRANSLATE('ABC12X','0123456789','          '),' ','')

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good place to use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select v.str, convert(varchar(max), '') as digits, convert(varchar(max), '') as chars, 1 as lev
      from (values ('AB12C34DE')) v(str)
      union all
      select stuff(str, 1, 1, ''),
             (case when left(str, 1) like '[0-9]' then digits + left(str, 1) else digits end),
             (case when left(str, 1) like '[a-zA-Z]' then chars + left(str, 1) else chars end),
             lev + 1
      from cte
      where str > ''
     )
select top (1) with ties cte.*
from cte
order by row_number() over (order by lev desc);
```

As the `values()` clause suggests, this will work on columns in a table as well as constants.